# Cut and paste data range to bottom of another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

I'm new to google app script and not sure how to solve this issue.

I have two sheets, "Main" and "Extract". Throughout the day, data is pasted into the "Extract" sheet, cleaned up (script removes certain columns and removes rows where a value in column A also exist in column A of the "Main" sheet), and then added to the "Main" sheet, which contains all of the cleaned up extracts pulled throughout the day.

I am trying to write a script that will take all of the cleaned up data in the "Extract" sheet and cut and paste it beneath the last row with data in the "Main" sheet.

Once cleaned up the "Extract" sheet always has 8 columns (A-H), but the amount of rows varys each time. I do not need the header or column 8 (H) pasted to the "Main" sheet, only A2:G (stopping at the last row with data).

So far this is all I have been able to come up with (it is likely very wrong)

```
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
.offset(0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Please don't ask for full feature code... this is not the purpose of this community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are trying to do.

```
var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Extract");
// skip row 1 (header) and beyond column G
var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,7);
sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Main");
var rows = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
// search for first blank row column 1
for( var i=0; i<rows.length; i++ ) {
  if( rows[i][0] === "" ) {
    var offset = sheet.getRange(1,1).offset(i,0);
    range.copyTo(offset);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @TheWizEd, thanks for your help! The code works great, however I'm realizing that because columns H-J on "Main" contain formulas that run down 1000 rows, the data from the "Extract" sheet is being pasted 1 row below the last formula row.

How can I change this so the data is pasted below the last row of A-G in "Main", and not the formula rows H-J?

Comment: @Jesse without seeing your spreadsheet or full function i can't explain.  A sheet named "Extract" and "Main" do exist in your spreadsheet?

Comment: The code works great now, however I'm realizing that because columns H-J on "Main" contain formulas that run down 1000 rows, the data from the "Extract" sheet is being pasted 1 row below the last formula row. How can I change this so the data is pasted below the last row of A-G in "Main", and not the formula rows H-J? – Jesse 2 mins ago    edit

Comment: @Jesse, if you've filled in your sheet with formulas in anticipation of data, you really don't need to do that provided the forumals can be copied.  In that case you could extent the range to 8 or 9 columns.. copyTo copies both values and formulas and adjust formulas for change in cell address.

Comment: @Jesse if that is not the case then a search for the first empty row in column 1 could be done to determine where to paste

Comment: Unfortunately the formulas do not exist in the "Extract" sheet, only in "Main", so they can't be copied over. What would I need to chane about this script to search for the first empty in column 1?

Comment: @Jesse you need to find the last row in a certain column with data. There are many questions already asking this here on SO. Review them thoroughly, and if you still have a specific issue after attempting to implement your informed solution, ask a new question (and include your research and attempts).

Comment: @Jesse i have edited the code above to show how to find the first blank cell and copy the range